# Contrast of hyperlinks

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks

Is it possible to increase the contrast between normal text and hyperlink text?

In this example, you can barely tell the difference... the words "Slip Rings" are a hyperlink:

[image]

It's not obvious until you roll your mouse over it and the underline appears. Maybe have a permanent underline?

Comment: Agreed!  Really, I think contrast across the site could stand to be improved.

Comment: For me it is this and the title headers are not very clear, I think I prefer them bolded.

Comment: @Kortuk: If you make hyperlinks bold, then wouldn't that be confusing if someone wanted to highlight a non-hyperlinked phrase by making it bold?

Comment: @BG100, sorry, I added a second note at the same time. When I use header tags like <h3></h3> I think they are not as clear anymore, almost looking like text.

Comment: I'll make some tweaks.

Comment: @Jin, thanks! That would be great. Can you also take a moment on the headers?

Comment: @kortuk I don't think the question header needs to be styled. Since contextually it's different from a body text link. If you're already on the question page, chances are you rarely click on the question title text.

Comment: @jin, I often use <h1><h2><h3> tags to distinguish headers in an answer. On [this answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2844/calculating-inclination-using-accelerometer/2850#2850) I used the header just to section of the information for the reader and it is very hard to tell which sections are titles. It blends in and loses its advantage.

Comment: @Kortuk, sorry I misunderstood before. I thought you were talking about the main question title header text. I have made the body section header text(h1-4) bold. You'll see the changes in the next deployment.

Comment: @jin, I figured out the communication issue and got an example SO style. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @Kortuk - You can also prefix your headers with `#`, `##`, or `###` (equivalent to H1, H2, and H3 respectively) to get the same effect.

Comment: @reemrevnivek, thanks for the info. I normally spend all my time on the answer and almost none on the formating, just use basic HTML tags, but that saves time.

Answer (score 3):

I made the links inside of the question/answer body to be underlined. The change will be in the next production deployment.

Comment: @Jin - Maybe your monitor or your eyes are better able to distingush colors better than mine, but I still cannot identify in comments on the parent site. Why didn't you extend this change to comments?

Comment: @Jin - More to the point, could you please make this change?

Comment: @reem i made the comment links lighter. the change will be in the next deployment.

Comment: @Jin - Thanks!  Much better now.

Comment: @Jin - You left the a:visited color dark.  [This question](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/541/link-contrast-in-comments-on-main-site-needs-to-be-fixed) suggests that this should also be changed.  Sorry to keep bugging you about this...

Comment: @reemrevnivek i'll fix that too.