# Link contrast in comments on main site needs to be fixed!

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Contrast of hyperlinks](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/499/contrast-of-hyperlinks)

We've already had [this](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/499/1240) question and it seems that the problem was solved, but I've noticed that that solution does not include comments.

In my opinion, links in comments should be changed to look like links in questions or answers.

UPDATE:

It seemed to be fixed, from this:
[image]

But then I saw [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/14352/1240):

[image]

So in one place the comments are fixed and in another they aren't.

Comment: Just to illustrate the problem, take a look at [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/13023/1240) question. Also Meta does not seem to be affected.

Comment: Meta can't be affected, it's yellow vs. black.  The main site is navy blue vs. black, so it's significantly harder.

Comment: Resolution is pending.  See comments to [this answer](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/499/contrast-of-hyperlinks/510#510)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have changed the visited color to be lighter. this change will be in the next deployment.

Comment: thank you!

Answer (score 2):

After you click on a link, your browser re-colors the text.  The CSS contains:

```
a:visited{color:#234862;}
```

This means that visited links look different from links you've already seen, which can help you as you browse.  Take a look, for example, at the list of questions in the right sidebar. Mine (from that question) look like this:

[image: main site links]

Sites you've already visited (which probably includes the link you posted...) will be in the darker color.  Note that the link to your profile is in the same dark blue color.

The fact that you see it on some links but not others is understandable and by design.

The fact that you can't tell it's a link after you've visited it, however, should not be by design.

<sub>*Note: This is intended to be an explanation of the observed behavior, not a solution to the problem.</sub>